# what is the default pop up replacement now?

Tags: popup

I know pop ups are [not good](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html) and should be avoided if possible but is that really true that now, whenever i think of using a pop up, i should always be considering other options? Are there any exceptions? And the last question is: what is the default replacement for pop ups?

Comment: Have you considered simply not using a popup at all? What's the practical problem with a normal link that you are trying to solve here? Are we talking complex web apps or normal web sites?

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to find out. I am not going to use pop ups but I'm just trying to understand the case better, are there any exceptions and what is the better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Web2.0" pop-up might be a lightbox.  I hope these are just a passing fad, because they are kind of annoying (a lot like pop-ups).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)

Comment: If you find it annoying, do you have any alternatives that you prefer?

Answer (score 6):

You can use any javascript based dialog. Look for example at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

Banners, like you get at the top of Stack Overflow to tell you about badges, comments, see the FAQ if you're a new user are my favorite.  They don't really get in the way and can link to the main content.

Comment: That's kind of nice too. I like it. The only disadvantage with that is the limited space. It can be good for short messages and maybe a link to a more detailed information (assuming you have a separate page for it). I don't think a banner that takes over 1/3 of the page is a good thing.

Comment: i disklike them when their appearance is animated. I often use a web browser via RDP, and this kind of gratuitous animation slows everything down terribly. (Facebook is the worst over RDP.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Pop-ups are completely acceptable in certain contexts. The aversion to pop-ups arose from having pop-up foisted on users in the form of advertisements. I think that pop-ups are still a valid device in the correct case.

My rule of thumb is to not make any decisions for the user that they can make themselves. This typically includes opening a pop-up since they could right-click and choose "open link in new window" if they so desired.

Do you want to capture of a piece of user input without allowing any further interaction? A modal dialog is your friend.

there are cases where you want to offer a bit of useful info or a quick reference that doesn't necessitate closing off the rest of the web page or navigating to a different location. This could be addressed using some javascript and floating div's but many times a pop-up will do what you want without being obtrusive to a user.

I tend to read resources from the likes of 37 signals and UIE to keep up with the best ways to enhance user experience without alienating a user.